# Read Home and Office location set in google maps in android code

Tags: android, maps

Google maps app allow us to set Home and Office location.Is there a way i can read these locations in my android code.I am writing an app and i need to know whether user has set his/her Home and Office location in google maps and if yes then what are they?I can put the google map in my app and can ask the user to locate his/her Home and office location but it would be duplicate effort by the user and won't look good.Any other suggestions are also welcome here

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Geocoding API for getting the address - [GeoCoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Geocoding will convert co-ordinates to human readable and vice versa. I need to know the location user has saved in Google Maps as Home and Office. There is a feature in google maps where you can set your office and home. I need to fetch this detail in my android code